# How do you trigger cloud functions when someone follows someone else using Firebase? I'm using Atom and Xcode

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase and I want to trigger a notification when 'person A' follows 'person B'.

This is my code:

```
exports.observeFollowing = functions.database.ref('/added/{followerID}/{followingID}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
var followerID = context.params.followerID;
var followingID = context.params.followingID;

console.log('User: ' + followerID + ' is following: ' + followingID);

//trying to figure out fcmtoken to send a notification
return admin.database().ref('/users/' + followingID).once('value', snapshot => {

var userWeAreFollowing = snapshot.val();

return admin.database().ref('/users/' + followerID).once('value', snapshot => {

  var userDoingTheFollowing = snapshot.val();

  var payload = {
    notification: {
      title: "Someone added you as a friend",
      body: userDoingTheFollowing.username + ' is now following you'
    }
  }

  return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(userWeAreFollowing.fcmToken, payload)
    .then(response => {
      console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
      return response
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error sending message:", error);
    });
   })
  })
 });
```

The console prints the `('User: ' + followerID + ' is following: ' + followingID)` part but doesn't show the notification. I've tested cloud notifications before and they worked but this doesn't work for some reason. In the logs, it says:

> Successfully sent message: { results: [ { error:
> [FirebaseMessagingError] } ]," "failureCount: 1," "successCount: 0,"

So I know that everything up until the `console.log('User: ' + followerID + ' is following: ' + followingID);` works. But I'm not sure if the notification function is even being called. Am I missing a semicolon or something else? I really can't figure it out. Also, what does `failureCount` mean? Is it talking about the notifications function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the Cloud Functions [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions), you need to manage the asynchronous Firebase operations by using promises. You are using the callback version of the [`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) method: you need to use the promise version, as follows:

```
exports.observeFollowing = functions.database.ref('/added/{followerID}/{followingID}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

    const followerID = context.params.followerID;
    const followingID = context.params.followingID;

    let userWeAreFollowing;

    console.log('User: ' + followerID + ' is following: ' + followingID);


    return admin.database().ref('/users/' + followingID).once('value')
        .then(snapshot => {

            userWeAreFollowing = snapshot.val();

            return admin.database().ref('/users/' + followerID).once('value')

        })
        .then(snapshot => {

            const userDoingTheFollowing = snapshot.val();

            const payload = {
                notification: {
                    title: "Someone added you as a friend",
                    body: userDoingTheFollowing.username + ' is now following you'
                }
            }

            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(userWeAreFollowing.fcmToken, payload)

        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error sending message:", error);
            return null;
        });

});
```

---

If you want to log a message in the console upon success do as follows:

```
    // ...
    .then(snapshot => {

        const userDoingTheFollowing = snapshot.val();

        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: "Someone added you as a friend",
                body: userDoingTheFollowing.username + ' is now following you'
            }
        }

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(userWeAreFollowing.fcmToken, payload)
    })
    .then(response => {
         console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
         return null;
    }).catch(function (error) {
         console.log("Error sending message:", error);
         return null;
    });
```

Comment: The notifications don't appear. I still get a 'failureCount' message and "canonicalRegistrationTokenCount: 0" message. Does Simulator not trigger the notifications or is it another problem?

Comment: I also got these errors: "Successfully sent message: { results: [ { error: [FirebaseMessagingError] } ]," and " canonicalRegistrationTokenCount: 0,". I updated everything in my project and don't know what else to try. Any help would be appreciated.